# How can I install more than one different version of nginx on Linux?

Tags: linux, http, nginx, installation, server

How can I install more than one different version of nginx on Linux? E.g., 1.8.* and 1.9.*

And it must be running all versions at the same time!

Comment: it's not very practical to run more then one version of Nginx on the same box IMO. 

You will need to setup some sort of proxy i.e. HAproxy or even Nginx ;P to distribute the load onto ports of which you will be running your deferent Nginx versions. As you can't have more then one instance of Nginx bind to the same port. So either your proxy or LB will be on different  box or you need to run everything on the same instance. It would be easier to have 2 different servers each with their own Nginx. IMO

Comment: What the reason to do so?

Comment: There would be no conflict, for example, the v1.8. *, the 127.1.8. * IP range to work with the v1.9. *  and the 127.1.9. * IP range.

For Apache, this works without problems, the nginx is newer development than Apache , I doubt that could not be resolved.

Comment: Alexey Ten - 
The target is create a testing environment, in which different settings which can be tested in different configurations, a website in operation. I know that depends on PHP from, but the http server can interfere with proper operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a job for Docker.

The Docker program will let you run multiple versions of software on the same Linux kernel.

After installing Docker, you need to create containers each running different versions of nginx that you specify. To get started I advice this webpage: *[nginx (official image)](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/)*